# How to calculate tax percentage in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time asking a question here, so I hope I'll do it correctly.

Just to give context, I'm developing a small website where lawyers can buy a digital version of some legal documents, but I'm having trouble calculating tax on the total cost.

The taxes are calculated with two rates used in the province of Quebec, Canada: GST (5%) and QST (9.975%). Both rates are calculated using the subtotal amount. Here's what I tried so far:

```js
$("#formchoix #checkall").click(function () {
        var tps = 0.05; //5%
        var tvq = 0.09975; //9.975%
        var subtotal = 0;
        var total = 0;
        if ($("#formchoix #checkall").is(':checked')) {
            $("#formchoix input[type=checkbox].checkchoix").each(function () {
                //check all forms
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                $(".checknom").prop("checked", true);
                $(".checkid").prop("checked", true);

                subtotal += 15; //each form is 15$

                $('#subtotal').html(subtotal + '.00$'); //subtotal shown to user

                var taxes = subtotal * tps * tvq;
                total = subtotal + taxes;
                $('#totalcost').html(total.toFixed(2) + '$'); //total shown to user
                $('#inputTotal').val(total.toFixed(2)); //value to be sent to server
            });

        } else {
            $("#formchoix input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                //reset everything: checkboxes, value and total shown to user
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                $(".checknom").prop("checked", false);
                $(".checkid").prop("checked", false);

                subtotal = 0;
                total = 0;
                $('#subtotal').html('0.00$');
                $('#totalcost').html('0.00$');
                $('#inputTotal').val('0.00');
            });
        }
    });
```

The above code doesn't give me the right number though. For example, if my subtotal is 30$, it will show 30.15$ instead of 30.49$ like it's supposed to (based on a tax calculator online).

I've also tried using values like 1.05 and 1.09975 and multiplicating them to the subtotal directly using `total = subtotal * tps * tvq`, but the total gave me 30.64$ (if the subtotal is 30$ like my previous example)

Clearly what I did is wrong, so how can I make sure the total is right?

Comment: The problem is with your tax calculation code. Do it like this -> var taxes = (subtotal * tps) + (subtotal * tvq);

Comment: Try `subtotal*(1 + 0.05 + 0.09975)` otherwise you are taxing taxes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`30 * 0.05 * 0.09975 = 0.149625`, which is rounded to 0.15 by calling `toFixed(2)`. Math doesn't lie. As others suggested, you're taxing taxes.

```
var taxes = subtotal * tps * tvq;
total = subtotal + taxes;
```

should be changed to

```
total = subtotal + subtotal * tps + subtotal * tvq;
```

or

```
total = subtotal * (1 + tps + tvq);
```

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think of that. I'm not used to doing maths with jQuery. Thank you, it worked like a charm

Comment: @Ikotai jQuery is there just to show the results, math rules don't change :)

Comment: I didn't realise it was a maths issue, I thought it was my code. Again, thanks a lot. I'll try to understand my code more and take that into consideration next time I want to ask a question :)